# Page hit counter with AJAX - how to handle multiple visits of same user?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, session, hitcounter

I created simple hit counter that sends ajax requests to determine how long visitor is viewing the page.

In JS im just hitting PHP file every few seconds:

```
var ajaxreq = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajaxreq.open("GET", "visitlogger.php", true); 
ajaxreq.send();
```

PHP file (visitlogger.php) stores data in MySQL database.
- stores "first hit timestamp"
- stores HTTP_REFERER, user agent, IP etc.
- updates "last hit timestamp" if session ID exists (to check how long user had page opened)

Now I need some cookie or something, to group visits by unique visitors.

How to do it?

Comment: http://samy.pl/evercookie/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is save two cookies, first which will have small expiration and other as long say 4-6months, if the second cookie is set you know he ain't a unique visitor, but still drawbacks are:

1) if cookies disabled?

2)if cookies are cleared?

Edit code:

```
  if (!isset($_COOKIE["visit_id"])) { //short cookie

    //log in db

    setcookie("visit_id", session_id(), time()+60*60*1, "/"); //set cookie for a day 

  } 


  if (!isset($_COOKIE["visit_long"])) { //long cookie

    //log in db


    setcookie("visit_long", session_id(), time()+60*60*24*30*6, "/"); //set cookie long for 6 months

  } else {

    if (!isset($_COOKIE["visit_id"])) {

    //not a unique visitor


    setcookie("visit_id", session_id(), time()+60*60*1, "/"); //set cookie for one day

   }

 }
```

Comment: I can ignore users with disabled cookies. Cleared cookies is a problem, but I think there is no way to workaroud this. Can you provide some code for JS script and PHP part?

Comment: Not a js guy, i can give php and you can ping that file